# Varnish 3.0 with Nginx SSL Termination on Ubuntu 12.04 [endless loops issue]

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, varnish

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04) and successfully setup my server which works as follows:

**OVER HTTPS**

Visitor > Nginx (port 443) > SSL Termination > Varnish (port 80) > Apache (port 8080)

**OVER HTTP**

Visitor > Varnish (port 80) > Apache (port 8080)

Now when I visit my site on HTTPS, it goes on "endless loop". I get "Page isn't redirecting properly" error on the browser.

I tried to tell Apache to return response on HTTPS as follows:

Added this to my Nginx config:

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;

Also added this to my .htaccess file:

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== on) {
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Protocol https HTTPS=on

What possibly is going wrong? What do I need to configure to come out of the loop?

NOTE: I'm running Varnish 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving Varnish out of the path when using HTTPS

So... instead of ==>>

Visitor > Nginx (port 443) > SSL Termination > Varnish (port 80) > Apache (port 8080)

Just use this ==>>

Visitor > Nginx (port 443) > SSL Termination > Apache (port 8080)

Comment: No. It's not working :(

I even tried to add following to my Nginx server block

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;

It continues to redirect.

I also added this to my .htaccess file, but it isnt working:

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== on) {

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Protocol https HTTPS=on