# Redirect loop with Nginx SSL termination via Varnish/Apache On Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, varnish

I have a setup where Apache listens on port 8080 behind Varnish 4 on port 80, but my client needs ssl working on the site so I setup Nginx for SSL termination on port 443 using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Everything works fine at first on http, but on attempting to load the site on https, scripts required by the site won't load, So I decided to change the site url in `Settings > General` to an https url, on saving changes, I get a redirect loop error in Chrome.

I couldn't access the site's wordpress dashboard to change the url back so I had to do it via phpmyadmin. But now when the site is accessed via https, the site breaks cause the scripts it requires to render content aren't authenticated.

Someone else has the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152764/varnish-3-0-with-nginx-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-12-04-endless-loops-issue) but it doesn't look like it was solved.

How can I have the site on just `https` without a redirect loop in Chrome?

Answer (score 13):

After hours of trying to get this to work, I finally found a fix, all I had to was add an `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` in my `wp-config.php` just before changing the site url, this way:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
     $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

One more thing I had to do was to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;` to my `default` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` so it looks like this:

```
server {                                                      
        ...                                                    
        location / {                                          
                 ...
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
          }
  }
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Man! You are just awesome.... This saved me hours of work... You are the man!!!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: This was very helpful! I had to change `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;` to`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` The header that nginx passes needs to match what the wp-config.php file is looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can set this header in nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

and then in your apache vhost configuration:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
```